# What's python's Task equivalent of a JS' promise.then().catch() without await?

Tags: python, promise, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine

This adds an success/error handler to the future like:

```js
async function send(item) {
    // ...
}

for (const item of items) {
    const sendPromise = send(item);
    sendPromise
        .then(x => console.log(x))
        .catch(x => console.error(x))
}
```

instead of await-ing like:

```js
for (const item of items) {
    const sendPromise = send(item);
    try {
        const x = await sendPromise
        console.log(x)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```

What's python's Task equivalent of a JS' promise.then() without await?

```py
async def send(item):
    pass

for item of items:
    send_coro = send(item)
    send_task = asyncio.create_task(send_coro)
    # ?????
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am reading the JavaScript correctly, it adds an error handler to the future. A literal translation would be something along the lines of:

```
def _log_err(fut):
    if fut.exception() is not None:
        print(f'error: {fut.exception()}')

for item in items:
    send_future = asyncio.create_task(send(item))
    send_future.add_done_callback(_log_err)
```

Note that the above is not idiomatic, as it resorts to callbacks and is less elegant than the original JavaScript, where `then` and `catch` return new futures which chain nicely.

A better approach is to use a helper coroutine to host the `await`. This doesn't require the outer function to be `async def`, thus being equivalent to the above:

```
async def _log_err(aw):
    try:
        return await aw
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'error: {e}')

for item in items:
    asyncio.create_task(_log_err(send(item)))
```